# $lookup not working in nested field array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have notifications schema like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var NotificationsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User", //this may be null if user is not in system
  },
  userEmail: {
    type: String,
    //required: [true, "User Email cannot be empty"],
  },
  notifications: [
    {
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      notificationTemplate: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "NotificationTemplate",
        required: [true, "Notification Template cannot be empty"],
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
        //required: [true, "Message cannot be empty"],
      },
      attachment: {
        type: [String],
      },
      by: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User", //if some other user send me notification
      },
      protocols: {
        type: [
          {
            type: String,
            enum: ["email", "webapp", "smstext"],
          },
        ],
        validate: {
          validator: function (protocols) {
            return protocols.length > 0;
          },
          message: "At least one protocol is required",
        },
        required: [true, "Protocols for Notification cannot be empty"],
      },
      isRead: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      readOn: {
        type: Date,
      },
      sentWeb: {
        type: Date,
      },
      sentEmail: {
        type: Date,
      },
      sentSmsText: {
        type: Date,
      },
      isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      //Make sure to save all subject and message variable in notificationParameters
      notificationParameters: Object, //here saved any other info
      createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
      },
    },
  ],
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

let Notifications;

if (!mongoose.models["Notifications"]) {
  Notifications = mongoose.model("Notifications", NotificationsSchema);
} else {
  Notifications = mongoose.models["Notifications"];
}
module.exports = Notifications;
```

I am trying to find user notifications with pagination and populate notificationTemplate but somehow it never populate notificationTemplate field. Each user can have multiple documents in Notifications.

here is my try

```
  const doc = await Notifications.aggregate([
    { $match: { user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId) } },
    //{ $unwind: "$notifications" },
    { $match: { "notifications.protocols": { $in: ["webapp"] } } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        localField: "notificationTemplate",
        //localField: "notifications.notificationTemplate", //not working
        foreignField: "_id",
        from: "NotificationTemplate", // Replace with the actual collection name
        as: "notificationTemplate",
        // as: "notificationTemplateInfo",//not working
      },
    },
    { $sort: { "notifications.createdOn": -1 } }, // Sort by createdOn field in descending order
    { $skip: (page - 1) * parseInt(itemsPerPage) },
    { $limit: parseInt(itemsPerPage) },
    { $project: { notifications: 1 } },
    //{ $unwind: "$notifications" },
 ]);
```

Here is how i recieve data, note that notificationTemplate is always id

```
 [
   {
    attachment: [],
    protocols: [ 'email', 'webapp' ],
    isRead: false,
    isDeleted: false,
    createdOn: 2023-11-03T16:46:59.372Z,
    notificationTemplate: 65451f5277306d1d2c418cd5,
    url: '/session/654524e33e894e35ac4c00b9',
    by: 63a66a814e32a254204776e8,
    sentWeb: 2023-11-03T16:50:43.769Z,
    notificationParameters: { subject: 'Networking iDea' },
    sentEmail: 2023-11-03T16:50:45.766Z,
    _id: 654524e59c36fe07f08542c5
  }
]
```

Here is sample data in mongodb. Note, Each user will have multiple notifications documents

```
   {
       "_id":{"$oid":"65461f21db7f106a02931cc2"},
       "createdDate":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1699030019372"}},
       "user":{"$oid":"63a24f8a9d7babc0c0e51743"},
       "userEmail":"s.m.sami125@gmail.com",
       "notifications":[
        {
          "attachment":[],
          "protocols":["email","webapp"],
          "isRead":false,
          "isDeleted":false,
          "createdOn":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1699030019372"}},
          "notificationTemplate":{"$oid":"65451f5277306d1d2c418cd5"},
          "url":"/session/654524e33e894e35ac4c00b9",
          "by":{"$oid":"63a66a814e32a254204776e8"},
          "sentWeb":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1699030243769"}},
          "notificationParameters":{"subject":"Networking iDea"},
          "sentEmail":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1699030245766"}},
          "_id":{"$oid":"654524e59c36fe07f08542c5"}
        }
       ]
   }
```

when i try this, it is populating document fine.

```
const c = await Notifications.find({ user: req.params.userId }).populate(
    "notifications.notificationTemplate"
  );
```

Comment: please show one sample data of Notificattion in MongoDB, not a aggregate result

Comment: I added sample data

Comment: You can't solve this problem with simple aggregate because “notifications” is array.  In aggregation you can match one field to another collection’s data.
There is noway to loop in aggregate. Ok?

Comment: well any other way to solve ?

Answer (score -1):

In $lookup, localField must be different from as field.

Otherwise, it won't work correctly.

For example, notificationTemplete field is 65451f5277306d1d2c418cd5 but there is no data with _id like that in NotificationTemplete collection.

result's notificationTemplete field won't be changed to Object and remaining in 65451f5277306d1d2c418cd5.

In your query, 'localField' is 'notificationTemplate' and 'as' is also 'notificationTemplate'.

Change one and it'll works correctly.

For example

```
  $lookup: {
    localField: "notificationTemplate",
    foreignField: "_id",
    from: "NotificationTemplate", 
    as: "notificationTemplateInfo",
  },
```

Then result will be

```
 [
   {
    attachment: [],
    protocols: [ 'email', 'webapp' ],
    isRead: false,
    isDeleted: false,
    createdOn: 2023-11-03T16:46:59.372Z,
    notificationTemplateInfo: 65451f5277306d1d2c418cd5,
    url: '/session/654524e33e894e35ac4c00b9',
    by: 63a66a814e32a254204776e8,
    sentWeb: 2023-11-03T16:50:43.769Z,
    notificationParameters: { subject: 'Networking iDea' },
    sentEmail: 2023-11-03T16:50:45.766Z,
    _id: 654524e59c36fe07f08542c5
  }
]
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Good luck.

Comment: Its not working